# SCSS pre-processor in Hugo

Tags: hugo

Looking to find out what pre-processor Hugo uses for compiling SCSS to CSS. I can't find it in the docs, training resources, blog posts. For example, is it using Dart Sass, LibSass, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Hugo uses [LibSass](https://github.com/sass/libsass) through [golibsass](https://github.com/bep/golibsass), an implementation made by the main developer of Hugo (bep). I base this on the fact that golibsass is included in [resources/resource_transformers/tocss/scss/tocss.go](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/102ec2da7adcc4afb7050b17989f0486f8379679/resources/resource_transformers/tocss/scss/tocss.go#L25), and that LibSass is [referenced in several issues](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/search?q=libsass&unscoped_q=libsass&type=Issues).

Answer (score 1):

Currently is using **LibSass**,

many things can not be used like @use, but have been considering switching to [DartSass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) (see [godartsass](https://github.com/bep/godartsass))

---

I don't know why you're asking this question, but for me, I was trying to adopt some new syntax ([@use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use)), and it never worked, and that's when I learned about it. I hate using obsolete stuff ([@import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)), so I'm going to package it into CSS by hand, feed it to Hugo, and then change it after Hugo really supports it.

Here are some links that may be useful for someone

- [Are there plans to support dart-sass?](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/question-are-there-plans-to-support-dart-sass-and-its-newly-introduced-use-modular-system/21882)
- [Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)
- [Hugo - SASS and @use](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/hugo-sass-and-use/23803/2)